# Conjecture regarding the sum of prime factors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures

### $\text{Notations}$

Let $\pi(n)$ be the prime countiong function.

Let denote $\alpha(n)$ the sum of the prime factors of $n$. In other words, if $$n=p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_m^{x_m}$$ then $\alpha(n)=p_1+p_2+...+p_m$

*(I changed the notation; It was pointed out in the comments that $\omega$ is another function and it was misleading)*

---

### $\text{Statement}$

> Prove or disprove that there exist infinitely many composite positive integers $n$ such that $\alpha(n)+1|n+1$.

---

### $\text{Important}$

I made a new thread in which the question is posted with some new conditions. I am now interested in the squarefree solutions of the above equation. New problem link: [Conjecture on the sum of prime factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720724/nt-conjecture-2-on-the-sum-of-prime-factors)

Comment: Note: you might want to change notation—usually $\omega(n)$ is used for the number of prime factors of $n$ (or $\Omega(n)$ if they are counted with multiplicity), and $\psi(n)$ is used for [Chebyshev's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function). Really the use of $\psi(n)$ is unnecessary—you can just say that $n$ is not prime (or not a prime power, depending on whether you count prime factors with multiplicity).

Comment: Sorry, i only used the notations to express myself in a simpler manner , they are not imoortant

Comment: It is true that we cannot PROVE that there are infinite many primes $p$ such that $p^2-2$ is prime. But the extended Bunyakovsky conjecture implies it and based on the $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$-approach for the probability that $n$ is prime, it is the case. Are you interetsted in the solutions upto some more or less large serach limit ? Maybe, we find another infinite family of solutions.

Comment: Yes i would be very grateful if you found solutions

Comment: For a start , the solutions upto $n=1000$ are : $$[21, 115, 120, 168, 174, 279, 329, 450, 550, 594, 650, 702, 710, 731, 735, 759]$$

Comment: There are $1201$ solutions upto $n=10^6$ and $5608$ solutions upto $n=10^7$

Comment: There are $27905$ solutions upto $n=10^8$

Comment: I wonder whether we can prove that there are infinite many squarefree solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claim : $n:=2\cdot 3\cdot 5^{5m+4}$ is a solution for all $m\ge 1$

Proof :

The sum of the prime factors is obviously $10$. Because of $5^5\equiv 1\mod 11$ , we have $n\equiv 2\cdot 3\cdot 5^4\equiv -1\mod 11$ , hence $11\mid n+1$

Hence there are infinite many solutions.