# Conjecture on the sum of prime factors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, conjectures, divisor-sum

### $\text{Notations}$

Let $\pi(n)$ be the prime counting function.

Let denote $\alpha(n)$ the sum of the prime factors of $n$. (i.e. In other words, if $$n=p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_m^{x_m}$$ then $\alpha(n)=p_1+p_2+...+p_m$.)

*(I changed the notation; It was pointed out in the comments that $\omega$ is another function and it was misleading)*

---

### $\text{Statement}$

> Find whether the equation $\alpha(n)+1|n+1$ has infinitely many squarefree solutions. Moreover, show that one can find an infinitude of composite, non-squarefree solutions.

---

### $\text{Progress}$

The original question was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720572/nt-conjecture-2-on-the-sum-of-prime-factors) and Peter found the following general solution for non-squarefree integers:

> Claim : $n=2\cdot 3\cdot 5^{5m+4}$ is a solution for all $m\ge 1$
>
> Proof :  The sum of the prime factors is obviously $10$. Because of
> $5^5\equiv 1\mod 11$ , we have $n\equiv 2\cdot 3\cdot 5^4\equiv -1\mod
> > 11$ , hence $11\mid n+1$ Hence there are infinite many solutions.

So it has been proven that there are in fact infinitely many non-squarefree solutions (and the prime numbers are trivial solutions). The question about composite squarefree solutions still holds.

Comment: This is not a flaw, but shows that the solution is relatively easy if we allow any number. For squarefree numbers, I guess we must assume some open conjecture, but who knows ?

Comment: Well thats why i edited it into 2'. I specified it is squarefree

Comment: Upto $n=10^8$ , there are $12797$ solutions. Another (possibly infinite) family is $n:=(5m+2)(5m^2-2)$ , $m\ge 3$ , which is a solution if both factors are prime.